# Counting the same column on the same table under different alias?

Tags: mysql, join

I've two tables (well, 3, one is a user table with ID, name, email etc.. but that's bog standard).

Table 1:

```
Questions:
id (auto inc)
user_id (INT)
question (text)
parent (INT)
```

Table 2:

```
map_user_question_vote:
question_id (INT)
user_id (INT)
vote (INT)
```

It's a question and various anwsers site.

So a user posts a question and the parent is set to 0

When another user posts a reply, it goes to the same table, but the parent a field has the ID of the parent question.

Every user is presented with a vote button on questions and comments. (no downvoting or undoing).

What I need to do is to get a comment, find out its vote total and then the parent questions vote total too, all for a single user

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
  questions.id
, questions.question
, COALESCE(SUM(qv.vote), 0) as question_vote_score
, COALESCE(SUM(cv.vote), 0) as comment_vote_score
, parent.id as parentId
, parent.title as parentQuestion

from `questions`

join `questions` as `parent` on `questions`.`parent` = `parent`.`id`

join `map_user_question_vote` as `cv` on 
      `cv`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id`

join `map_user_question_vote` as `qv` on
      `qv`.`question_id` = `parent`.`id`

where questions.user_id = 1
  and questions.parent  > 0

group by questions.id

limit 5
```

What's happening, is it appears to be combining all the 'vote' totals, regardless of where they're coming from, questions or comments.

Any SQL gurus out there want to help me keep my hair? :)

EDIT: added http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5d08/1

Comment: What is `map_user_question_vote`?

Comment: SOrry that's the full name of my 'vote' table.. I just edited it for Stack Overflow... and was sloppy about it!

Comment: Can you put your tables with some data on http://sqlfiddle.com/? To run some tests?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2763a3/1

Comment: A better fiddle with more data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5d08/1

Answer (score 1):

If you join the tables this way and use the group by in the main query, you will first join the records of the `map_user_question_vote` table (twice) with the records of the `questions` table and sum will be calculated later for the same question groups (although the column names are different, the values will be the same).

You need to join with subqueries where you first calculate the sum of the votes. I.e.:

```
select
  questions.id
, questions.question
, parent.id as parentId
, parent.question as parentQuestion
, COALESCE(qv.sum_vote, 0) as parent_question_vote_score
, COALESCE(cv.sum_vote, 0) as comment_vote_score

from `questions`

join `questions` as `parent` on
     `questions`.`parent` = `parent`.`id`

left join (select `question_id`, sum(`vote`) as `sum_vote` from `map_user_question_vote` group by `question_id`) as `cv` on 
          `cv`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id`

left join (select `question_id`, sum(`vote`) as `sum_vote` from `map_user_question_vote` group by `question_id`) as `qv` on
          `qv`.`question_id` = `parent`.`id`

where questions.user_id = 1
  and questions.parent  > 0

limit 5
```

See the results in SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5d08/4).

Comment: Outstanding! I've always been wary of sub queries.. this is a great way to learn.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get it right, but I think, this may be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    q.id,
    q.user_id,
    q.question,
    SUM(IF(q.parent > 0, cv.vote, 0)) as comment_vote,
    SUM(IF(q.parent = 0, cv.vote, 0)) as question_vote
FROM map_user_question_vote as cv
INNER JOIN questions as q ON q.id = cv.question_id
WHERE q.user_id = 1
GROUP BY q.id, q.user_id, q.parent
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5d08/5